# Is the Math class a standard class of Java?

Tags: java

I know that String, Integer and Double are standard classes of Java, but would Math fall into this category?

You definitely do not have to import it like the Scanner class, which isn't a standard class of Java.

Perhaps I do not understand what a standard class is. Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: Yes, you do have to import Math to use it. But most of its methods are static, so you'd need to do either a static import or call the methods fully referenced. For example, you could do `java.util.Scanner myScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);` without having to import anything.

Comment: Yes, Math is a standard Java class. Scanner is, too. You have to import it because it lives in the `java.util` package.

Comment: Every class documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is considered standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> would Math fall into this category?

[Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html). It is documented as part of the JDK javadoc (since JDK 1.0) so you are guaranteed that it will exist in any JRE you'll ever encounter.

Note that since it resides in `java.lang`, you do not have to `import` it explicitly; you could:

```
import java.lang.Math;
```

but since all classes in `java.lang` are automatically imported (that includes `String` and `Integer` for instance), you need not do that.

This is a peculiar class in the sense that it cannot be instantiated and it only contains static methods and constants; apart from that you are sure to have it available, and that methods and constants obey the defined contract.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. I misunderstood what a standard class was. I thought it was a class that didn't need to be imported, but I never knew that those classes were automatically imported. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It comes with the SDK, if that is what "standard" meant.

It is part of the java.lang package, thus does not require import.

Answer (score 0):

yes Math class i standard, Math package is imported by default.
`java.lang.Math` class is part of `java.lang` class which are imported by default.

Go to this link if you want to learn about everything include in `java.lang` package http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html